# Undesireable D3 chord diagram link twist

Tags: d3.js, chord-diagram

I noticed that in some of the chord diagrams the link between 2 nodes has a "twist" in it.

For example, take a look at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1046712, between data.converters and data nodes, or between scale and util.

Or more prominently, in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062006, between the yellow and brown nodes.

I've seen this with my own chord diagrams between some adjacent nodes.  How can I get rid of this twist?

Answer (score 0):

The chord layout generates quadratic Bézier curves to connect the arc segments. You can't customise how these curves are generated, so in order to change their appearance you would need to either modify the source or select the path after it has been generated and modify in place.

In specific cases, simply rearranging the data might do the trick though. At the very least that will be much easier than anything else.